# Oracle Transaction under MS SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, transactions

I'm trying to get transactions working under SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services 2005) and Oracle with no luck. I'm using Oracle 10g.

I have created a Sequence Container, set its TransactionOption to "Required" and put inside it a DataFlow Task with TransactionOption = "Supported".

The server running SSIS has the MSDTC service running.

The DataFlow Task has, as source, a SQL Server OLEDB connection and as target an Oracle OLEDB connection.

When trying to execute it, I get the following errors:

```
Error: 0xC001402C at MediaMarketAnnullamento, Connection manager "ITMASORASVIL:1521/SVILUPPO.EDP": The SSIS Runtime has failed to enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error 0x8004D01B "The Transaction Manager is not available.".

Error: 0xC0202009 at MediaMarketAnnullamento, Connection manager "ITMASORASVIL:1521/SVILUPPO.EDP": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8004D01B.

Error: 0xC020801C at 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW, MAGAZZINO_MM_SHOW_SSIS [2187]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "ITMASORASVIL:1521/SVILUPPO.EDP" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Error: 0xC004701A at 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW, DTS.Pipeline: component "MAGAZZINO_MM_SHOW_SSIS" (2187) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Information: 0x40043009 at 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW, DTS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.

Information: 0x4004300B at 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW, DTS.Pipeline: "component "MAGAZZINO_MM_SHOW_SSIS" (2187)" wrote 0 rows.

Task failed: 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW

Information: 0x4001100C at 9999 - Insert_MAGAZZZINO_MM_SHOW: Aborting the current distributed transaction.

Information: 0x4001100C at Insert su Oracle: Aborting the current distributed transaction.

SSIS package "MediaMarketAnnullamento.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Any help?
Thanks

EDIT:
I just discovered that the server running Oracle is not, as I thought, Windows based but IBM ICS. I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: sounds like to me like this ought to fit better in serverfault.

Comment: no, this is programming related

Comment: I suggest that you avoid SSIS transactions. It prevented me from using working connections. Use SQL transactions inside SSIS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be a problem with MSDTC permissions [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/distributedservices/archive/2009/03/13/troubleshooting-msdtc-permission-issues-when-a-distributed-transaction-starts.aspx) MS blog post might help to debug it. Also I'm assuming that the permissions on the Oracle server are set correctly see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193893) MS kb article for help with this.

Comment: I suggest that you avoid SSIS transactions. It prevented me from using working connections. Use SQL transactions inside SSIS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is this doc of any use?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344212.aspx